# paypal express checkout dont display link to pay with credit card

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am using paypal sandbox and the php sample code. When I checkout with paypal, I never see a link to pay with credit card.  Do I need to do any special configuration to pay with a credit card?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following parameters set in your SetExpressCheckout request.

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Also make sure you're using API version 119.0, which is the latest version.

Comment: thank you. There are a few more things I needed to do. 1. Enable creditcards in my developer account,2. modify the file paypal_functions.php to receive those 3 parameters.  The file downloaded from paypal, does not have those values.

Comment: For future reference you may want to take a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  I keep it maintained better than PayPal seems to with their own, and it's also a lot quicker and easier to use.